# How to Inject a service call into another method?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

How do I mock an external call inside another method?

I mocked the service but since i am not passing the mocked service, the method does not get the mocked service.

Is there a way to inject the service?

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class MyKafkaClass(){

private final ISaveData saveData;

public void save(){
   //trying to mock the below method
   saveData.persistAddress(address);
}

}

public class MyKafkaTest(){

MyKafkaClass kafkaClass = mock(MyKafkaClass.class);
ISaveData saveData = mock(ISaveData.class);

@Test
public void saveTest(){

//Getting a null pointer exception at the below line. How do i inject ISaveData ?
doNothing().when(saveData.persistAddress(any());
kafkaClass.save();

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not mock a MyKafkaClass
try

```
    @InjectMocks
    MyKafkaClass kafkaClass;

    @Mock
    ISaveData saveData;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is wrong in many aspects:

1. Although the question is not spring related, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` should not be put on regular beans (such as MyKafkaClass), since you've tagged `spring-boot`, the chances are that you're already using `@SpringBootApplication` annotation on your main class which enables auto configuration automatically (see the source code of `@SpringBootApplication`, its marked with `@EnableAutoConfiguration` by itself.
2. Since you're using final field, the chances are that you have constructor injection:

```
public class MyKafkaClass {
  private final ISaveData saveData;
  public MyKafkaClass(ISaveData saveData) {
       this.saveData = saveData;
  }
  public void save(){
   //trying to mock the below method
   saveData.persistAddress(address);
  }
```

This is important because your test is also wrong conceptually: If you're testing `MyKafkaClass` it doesn't make sense to mock this class, instead you should create it and test it's code, that's the purpose of the test...

So your test should look like this:

```
public class MyKafkaTest(){

ISaveData saveData = mock(ISaveData.class);

@Test
public void saveTest(){

   // setup:
   // this is the 'object-under-test', not a mock!
   MyKafkaClass kafkaClass = new MyKafkaClass(saveData); // constructor injection is done here !
   // specify expectations for your stubs/mocks
   doNothing().when(saveData.persistAddress(any());

   // when: running the operation that you want to test
   kafkaClass.save();

   // then:
   // here you should verify the outcome of the test

}
```

Now its true that Mockito library provides some convenience stuff like `@InjectMocks` and `@Mock` (for that you should run the test with a special mockito runner (junit4) or extension (junit5) but this looks like pretty advanced stuff at this point, I suggest you to understand the concepts behind the proper unit testing first regardless the actual tooling...